# Replaced an outlet and a switch. Switch works but outlet doesn’t. No voltage measured

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker

I replaced an outlet and a light switch that are on the same breaker. Before replacing them I tested the voltage and got around 120 as expected and everything seemed to work. I replaced the outlet then I replaced the light/fan switch. The black wires, white wires and the ground are connected correctly. The light switch had 2 hot black wires and ground and everything is working with the light switch. I have tried redoing the wiring for the outlet, with a new outlet with no success. I have also tried testing for some voltage at the outlet and light switch. The switch shows 90-110V over the two black wires. The outlet shows nothing along any path where previously it did. I have a Leviton T5325-W at the outlet and can find no GFCI inside or outside my house connected to it.

Edit: Here are some photos of the wiring. It seems that I have 2 more lights connected to that breaker and another outlet. The lights and outlet work.
[image: Image of outlet]
[image: Image of outlet]
[image: Switch Wiring]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Check that the wire nut(s?) is properly twisted, those can get loose if sloppily done.

Comment: @whatsisname that wasn’t the issue but I did double check those just in case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to have connected a black wire to the grounding screw on the switch. I would guess that is the black wire that connects to the outlet that now has no voltage.

Presumably this is, in fact, NOT the way things were wired before. You likely need to connect that black wire to either the "always hot" or "switched hot" on the switch (dependng on whether the outlet should be switched) and either connect a bare grounding wire to the grounding screw and a ground screw on the box, or let the contact between the metal box and the metal yoke be the grounding connection for the switch.

Comment: Doing a continuity check on the on the black wire on the grounding screw  on the switch it is connected to ground so I’m not sure where things could be going wrong once I get to the outlet.

Comment: Given the metal box, **a switch** can ground via its mounting screws.  However, such a blunder with grounds indicates a critical, hazardous skill shortfall... it's time to get a book and read, as Google will never answer questions you don't know to ask!